# Postgresql query won't work

Tags: postgresql

[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWJqu.jpg)

any help appreciated,a week now and I am stuck -

many thanks if you can.

I added an image of the problem but it's disappeared

```
    WITH SITESmin as (
SELECT public.acc.Location_Easting_OSGR,    public.acc.Location_Northing_OSGR
FROM   acc Sites ,
ORDER BY  ( acc.Location_Easting_OSGR - Sites.SITE_ETG ) * ( acc.Location_Easting_OSGR - Sites.SITE_ETG ) + (acc.Location_Northing_OSGR - "public"."Sites"."SITE_ETG" ) * (     acc.Location_Northing_OSGR - "public"."Sites"."SITE_NTG" )
LIMIT 1
)
UPDATE ACC
SET acc.Location_Easting_OSGR = SITESmin.acc.Location_Easting_OSGR,
acc.Location_Northing_OSGR = SITESmin.acc.Location_Northing_OSGR
FROM SITESmin;
```

Here's the error:

```
Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ORDER"
LINE 4:     ORDER BY  ( acc.Location_Easting_OSGR - Sites.SITE_ETG )...
```

The ^ carat appears just after the Line 4: colon

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: In order to get an answer, you should improve and specify your question, also add related code about the issue.

Comment: Remove the `,` at the end of  `FROM   acc Sites ,`

Comment: Also: `FROM   acc Sites` does not seem to make sense. What are you trying to do there? If you give the table `acc` the alias `sites`  you can't use `acc` any more, you have to use `Sites`

Comment: guten tag herr horse with no name, you are not being helpful. If you wish to be of assistance please engage with me. I am not a school child. Please treat me with respect. Anthony

Comment: Mr. @Anthony500, there are rules and rules must be followed. About helpfulness and schoolchild... this questions problem is childish, Error code you supplied indicates where problem lies. Anyone familiar with SQL would notice reason of the problem immediately except a blind person. a_horse_with_no_name  did point out to you that there is a coma there which causes that error, yet  you ignore it and are being rude and act like a child .

Comment: Then you are calling me blind, the very behaviour of which you complain. I understand this place is replete with experts which is why I am here. If you do not wish to help then criticising me to boot is unhelpful when clearly I am having difficulty with the site and lacking support, where "rules" are blocking my progress, not for lack of trying I might add. I am not the one who is anonymous. Perhaps I should write the problem and not the solution, since I did not write this code originally. Starting over maybe. Try making your rules helpful instead of excluding the likes of me.

Answer (score 1):

on second look i noticed that this query has several problems.If you are using alias then stick to that alias, you have lots of fields defined wrongly or your query you posted has some missing parts and are not present in your example. and update part looks like is missing where condition ....
for example

```
SELECT public.acc.Location_Easting_OSGR,    public.acc.Location_Northing_OSGR
```

yet you defined alias  "Sites", which by the way is missing "as" syntax, it shouldve been

```
FROM   acc as Sites 


WITH SITESmin as (
SELECT Sites.Location_Easting_OSGR,    Sites.Location_Northing_OSGR
FROM   acc as Sites --,  <--- this coma was is causing that error, it does not belong there or some code is missing
ORDER BY  (Sites.Location_Easting_OSGR - Sites.SITE_ETG ) * ( Sites.Location_Easting_OSGR - Sites.SITE_ETG ) + (Sites.Location_Northing_OSGR -  Sites.SITE_ETG ) * (     Sites.Location_Northing_OSGR - Sites.SITE_NTG )
LIMIT 1
)
UPDATE ACC
SET acc.Location_Easting_OSGR = SITESmin.Location_Easting_OSGR,
acc.Location_Northing_OSGR = SITESmin.Location_Northing_OSGR
FROM SITESmin

---  missing where condition?
 ;
```

Comment: @Abelisto , It is optional for postgresql, yes. socks and shoes are optional for marathon too. yet its easier to run with them, so is proper query syntax easier to read and understand, reducing possible mistakes. For all i know, that mightve not been an alias but a different table joint and there was missing or misplaced coma

Comment: @Abelisto: `as` is not _required_ for column aliases